# Extract/Display JSON Wikipedia PHP

Tags: php, json, web, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am new to programming,
I need to extract the wikipedia content and put it into html.

```
            //curl request returns json output via json_decode php function
            function curl($url){
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $result;
            }

            $search = $_GET["search"];
            if (empty($search)) {
                //term param not passed in url
                exit;
            } else {
                //create url to use in curl call
                $term = str_replace(" ", "_", $search);
                $url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=".$search."&limit=1&namespace=0&format=jsonfm";
                $json = curl($url);

                $data = json_decode($json, true);
                $data = $data['parse']['wikitext']['*'];
           }
```

so I basically want to reprint a wiki page but with my styles and do not know how to do.
Any ideas, Thanks

Comment: $data = $data['parse']['wikitext']['*'];

Comment: Not sure if this is right